# Convert PHP SDK to make compatible with LARAVEL 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, sdk, yandex

I want to use Yandex Money as the payment solution of the website I'm working on.

Yandex already has a PHP SDK, and I want to understand how to convert this SDK to work with Laravel, or integrate it to be usable in Laravel.

Here is the code for Yandex SDK:
https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-money-sdk-php/

My hope is to have something similar to this Laravel version of the Facebook SDK.
https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk

Comment: You don't need to convert it to Laravel SDK. Just require it with composer and use it as documented within a class that you will be using Yandex SDK.

Comment: can you please explain it with example, as i dont understand how to do it

Comment: Just doing the 1st step of [installation guide](https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-money-sdk-php/#installation). And then use it whatever you want [Using Yandex.Money API requires following steps](https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-money-sdk-php/#payments-from-the-yandexmoney-wallet)